Luxon DateTime.toUTC().toFormat('t') adds a Non-Breaking Space Character
I recently began porting over a project from MomentJS to Luxon.
I have the following getter for BusinessHours
    get KeyBusinessHours(): string {
        if (this.Report.Type === ReportType.InternetHealth) {
            let start = DateTime.fromMillis(0);
            start = start.plus(GetDurationAmount('minutes', this.Options['KeyBusinessHoursStart']));
            let end = DateTime.fromMillis(0);
            end = end.plus(GetDurationAmount('minutes', this.Options['KeyBusinessHoursEnd']));
            // we don't want to convert to the users timezone, we just want to tell them what times were selected and the timezone they were selected in - so use UTC
            // (for example, user could be in EST but see '9:00 AM - 5:00 PM Central Standard Time' instead of just '12:00 PM - 8:00 PM')
            return `${start.toUTC().toFormat('t')} - ${end.toUTC().toFormat('t')}${this.Options['TimezoneForReport'] != null ?
                `(${this.Options['TimezoneForReport']})` : ''}`;
        }
        return undefined;
    }

which was ported over from the following MomentJS equivalent:
    get KeyBusinessHours(): string {
        if (this.Report.Type === ReportType.InternetHealth) {
            let start = moment(0);
            start.add(this.Options['KeyBusinessHoursStart'], 'minutes');
            let end = moment(0);
            end.add(this.Options['KeyBusinessHoursEnd'], 'minutes');
            // we don't want to convert to the users timezone, we just want to tell them what times were selected and the timezone they were selected in - so use UTC
            // (for example, user could be in EST but see '9:00 AM - 5:00 PM Central Standard Time' instead of just '12:00 PM - 8:00 PM')
            return `${start.utc().format('LT')} - ${end.utc().format('LT')} (${this.Options['TimezoneForReport']})`;
        }
        return undefined;
    }

The issue arises from the start.toUTC().toFormat('t'). I swapped to using this format ('t' instead of 'LT') based on the Luxon Formatting Docs, but I had a Jest test failing with the following message:
Expected substring: "2:00 AM - 4:00 AM"
Received string:    "2:00 AM - 4:00 AM"

Upon copying this into Notepad++, and clicking the 'Show All Characters' button, I realized that there are NNBSP characters hidden, so the compare instead looked like the following:
Expected substring: "2:00 AM - 4:00 AM"
Received string:    "2:00[NNBSP]AM - 4:00[NNBSP]AM"

I swapped the format to just be start.toUTC().toFormat('h:mm a'), and that fixed the issue. But is there any way to have Luxon use regular spaces instead of other characters when using their formats that add whitespace?
